# GeckoFx 60 Download + Open File

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

I want the embedded GeckoFx 60 to download a file and then open it with the default app.
By default it seems like GeckoFx does not do anything when the client requests to download a file.

To handle the download request I enabled an event handler:

```
LauncherDialog.Download += LauncherDialog_Download;
```

Then I found two possibilities to download or open a file via the HelperAppLauncher.
This one saves the requested file to a temp folder and opens it:

```
private void LauncherDialog_Download(object sender, LauncherDialogEvent e)
{
  // direct open, file will be stored in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\
  e.HelperAppLauncher.LaunchWithApplication(null, false);
}
```

I did not find a way to configure the save path. This other possible solution allows me to set the save path myself:

```
private void LauncherDialog_Download(object sender, LauncherDialogEvent e)
{
  nsILocalFileWin objTarget = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsILocalFileWin>("@mozilla.org/file/local;1");
  var downloadPath = @Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\CustomFolder\\" + e.Filename;
  using (nsAString tmp = new nsAString(downloadPath))
  {
    objTarget.InitWithPath(tmp);
  }
  e.HelperAppLauncher.SaveToDisk(objTarget, false);

  Task.Run(() =>
  {
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(downloadPath);
  });
}
```

That `Task.Run()` works, but is quite ugly and error prone. I could not find a better solution though. I tried adding a `WebProgressListener` like this:

```
var webProgressListener = new WebProgressListener();
webProgressListener.OnStatusChangeCallback+= OnStatusChangeCallback;
e.HelperAppLauncher.SetWebProgressListener(webProgressListener);
```

`webProgressListener.IsListening` is true, but my method `OnStatusChangeCallback` is never called. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a newer way?

How can I get notified that the download is completed?
Or how do I set the path for `LaunchWithApplication`?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but here is my solution :

```
Task.Run(() =>
        {
            long sizefirst = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                if (File.Exists(downloadPath))
                {
                    if (sizefirst == 0)
                    {
                        sizefirst = new FileInfo(downloadPath).Length;
                        continue;
                    }

                    long len_now = new FileInfo(downloadPath).Length;

                    if (len_now > sizefirst)
                    {
                        sizefirst = len_now;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(downloadPath);
                        break;
                    }



                }

            }    
        });
```

Comment: it controls the size of the file and when file's size dont change, i assumed that file download has been completed.